# No support for device type: power_supply 16.04

Tags: 16.04, battery, acpi

I am a new Ubuntu user who has installed Ubuntu 16.04 on my brand new laptop. The problem is that my battery doesn't get detected and so all power management issues don't work. After some researching in the internet I thought it was an acpi-issue and with a similar problem somebody had success in setting a grub boot parameter to `acpi=force`, but it didn't work for me.

When I type `acpi` in the terminal I get:
`No support for device type: power_supply`

But `acpi` is installed: `#acpi -v` gives me `acpi 1.7`

[Somewhere else](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/upower/+bug/1606159) a similar problem was called rather a problem of upower, but as far as I can see there was no solution offered. I have Upower client version 0.99.04